# Adding data to every other row, with first row being unique value, using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I need to add a new field to the attribute table. The first value (FID 1) in this new field is going to need to be a unique value - say 40,000.
From there, the next row (FID 2), and every other row (Should all be even FIDs) will be 40,010.

I then need to back track up, and label every other row, starting with labeled FID 3 (should all be odd FIDs), as 39,990.

Is there a way to do this using ArcPy?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use the FID as a basis for any calculation. It can change when you delete/add/edit features in a layer. If you want, you could create a new field and copy the FID to it for each row, that would use the FID values and protect them from being changed by ArcGIS.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't plan to use it as a basis for the code, just to give people an idea of how I needed the every-other row script set. I have a unique identifier Field I intend to use.

Comment: It's all using arcpy for a shapefile. Sorry I didn't specify as I this was already under GIS I assumed people would extrapolate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer should work, but I think it might be a little more clear/adaptable if we write a quick function:

```
def getVal(fid):
    if fid == 1:
        return 40000
    elif fid % 2 == 0:
        return 40010
    else:
        return 39990
```

This way you can change this function to do whatever you want and then call it in an update cursor:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('OCWR_point_count_stations', ['FID', 'NewField']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = getVal(row[0])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This is a workflow I use often in the python window because of its adaptability.  I just tested this code and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work, assuming the field FID starts at 1 and is numbered sequentially:
(code is untested)

```
with arcpy.da.updatecursor('TableName', ['FID', 'NewField'], sql_clause = ('None', 'Order By FID')) as uc:
    base = 40000
    counter = 10
    for row in uc:
        #Set the first value
        if row[0] == 1:
            row[1] = base
        #Set the value for odd rows
        elif row[0] % 2:
            row[1] = base - counter
            counter += 10
        #Only thing left is even rows
        else:
            row[1] = base + counter
        #commit the change
        uc.updateRow(row)
```